# Debugging views in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

I recently updated netbeans from 7.1.2 to 7.2.
Unfortunately, I can't find the way to activate the debugging views such as the list of breakpoints, the call stack and the threads list.

In netbeans 7.1 I can go in Window->Debugging to activate those but this menu disappeared in 7.2.

I checked if any plugin was missing but everything looks fine.

Currently, I only have the variables list/watches when I am debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked and I have them in Window -> Debugging. Maybe your installation is corrupt?

Comment: Relaunching the install script fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: Happened to me with Netbeans 8.0.2 after a OutOfMemoryError. Relaunching Netbeans solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same problems after updating my NB 7.2 with the latest updates: Sources, Threads, Breakpoints, Watches, Variables windows are always empty when I'm debugging a project. Used to work fine previously. I use free-form projects.
"Background project scanning" was running in some infinite loop, that was the reason. It was even difficult to quit NB.